# Cookies wont set if i specify an expiry date

Tags: php, cookies

this works:

```
setcookie('$id', $date);
```

But this doesnt set a cookie:

```
setcookie('$id', $date, 1000);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `1000` is a time in the past, so the cookie isn't set. The second parameter to `setcookie` is the server time, so to set one with expiry, you would use `time() + #` as the time parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The expire date should be Unix Timestamp. Quoting from [php.net/setcookie](http://php.net/setcookie):

> The time the cookie expires. This is a Unix timestamp so is in number
>   of seconds since the epoch. In other words, you'll most likely set
>   this with the time() function plus the number of seconds before you
>   want it to expire.

Your value represents the value 1000 seconds after Thursday, 1 January 1970.

You want to add 1000 seconds to the current [time()](http://php.net/time):

```
setcookie('$id', $date, time() + 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Third parameter should be like this:

```
setcookie('$id', $date, (time() + 1000));
```

`1000` is a time in the past so cookies aren't created.

With this approach, you're basically telling `current timestamp plus 1000 seconds`, so cookies will correctly be created.

Answer (score 0):

> expire
>
> The time the cookie expires. This is a Unix timestamp so is in number
> of seconds since the epoch. In other words, you'll most likely set
> this with the time() function plus the number of seconds before you
> want it to expire.

(see [setcookie() docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php))